Formatting phones numbers in pandas
Someone please tell me why the perfectly good code below is not taking out the non-alphanumeric characters from these phone numbers..? As you can see form the code below, when I print out the column, its still printing out the forward slash / and the dashes --
Please help
trying to remove the non-alphanumeric characters

add regex=True. Please be aware that images of data/code are not acceptable on SO.
